# Get id column name from POJO, using reflection

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable{

    @Id 
    @Column(name="MY_TABLE_ID") 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ,generator="SQ_MY_TABLE")    
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SQ_MY_TABLE", sequenceName="SQ_MY_TABLE")
    private Long myTableId;
```

How can I, using reflection, get the primary key column name from my POJO, defined with the `javax.persistence.Id` annotation? I'd have to find the `@Id` and then get the `name` property of the `@Column` annotation... I'm not sure how to do that...

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the all-by-yourself solution:

```
public static String getPKColumnName(Class<?> pojo) {

    if (pojo == null) 
        return null;

    String name = null;

    for (Field f : pojo.getDeclaredFields()) {

        Id id = null;
        Column column = null;

        Annotation[] as = f.getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation a : as) {
            if (a.annotationType() == Id.class) 
                id = (Id) a;
            else if (a.annotationType() == Column.class) 
                column = (Column) a;
        }

        if (id != null && column != null){
            name = column.name();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (name == null && pojo.getSuperclass() != Object.class)
        name = getPKColumnName(pojo.getSuperclass());

    return name;
}
```

Just a heads-up: This won't work for compound primary keys.

Comment: This won't work when the declaration of the ID is in a `MappedSuperclass`. But you could add a `if (name == null) return getPkColumnName(pojo.getSuperclass());` at the end.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Thanks for the info. I've changed the code.